# when client request to server, there is an error, saying 'Permission denied' from static directory

Tags: django, nginx, django-staticfiles

it seems like Nginx can not access the static files. I checked /var/log/nginx/error.log and got the following messages;

after checking this message, I put this code 'chmod -R 755' but it did not work (even 777) of course I did collectstatic and point to static root before this matter happened. I don't know why this happened and how to fix it... I have been struggling with this matter for more than 3 days now

`````
2021/05/12 00:17:07 [error] 12940#12940: *10 open() "/home/admin/github/djangobook/static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 101.191.5.33, server: 149.28.172.215, request: "GET /static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css HTTP/1.1", host: "easycoding.live", referrer: "http://easycoding.live/admin/login/?next=/admin/"
2021/05/12 00:17:07 [error] 12940#12940: *2 open() "/home/admin/github/djangobook/static/admin/css/base.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 101.191.5.33, server: 149.28.172.215, request: "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1", host: "easycoding.live", referrer: "http://easycoding.live/admin/login/?next=/admin/"
2021/05/12 00:17:07 [error] 12940#12940: *8 open() "/home/admin/github/djangobook/static/admin/css/login.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 101.191.5.33, server: 149.28.172.215, request: "GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1", host: "easycoding.live", referrer: "http://easycoding.live/admin/login/?next=/admin/"
2021/05/12 00:17:07 [error] 12940#12940: *8 open() "/home/admin/github/djangobook/static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 101.191.5.33, server: 149.28.172.215, request: "GET /static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js HTTP/1.1", host: "easycoding.live", referrer: "http://easycoding.live/admin/login/?next=/admin/"
2021/05/12 00:17:18 [error] 12940#12940: *1 open() "/home/admin/github/djangobook/static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 101.191.5.33, server: 149.28.172.215, request: "GET /static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css HTTP/1.1", host: "easycoding.live", referrer: "http://easycoding.live/admin/"
2021/05/12 00:17:18 [error] 12940#12940: *10 open() "/home/admin/github/djangobook/static/admin/css/dashboard.css" failed (13: Permission denied:````
`````

Comment: Every directory in the path needs to be readable by the process running Nginx.

Comment: How could I set Nginx to read all directory in the path?

Comment: You need to check all the [parent directory permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/do-the-parent-directorys-permissions-matter-when-accessing-a-subdirectory).

Comment: Thanks a lot! one more questions is okay? Why this happened? I did not set up this kind of the permission things on the directory or files.